# Twitter OAuth returns 401 invalid request token

Tags: laravel, twitter, oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel Socialite (specifically [this](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Twitter)) and all of a sudden, I'm getting this when returning to the callback:

`Received HTTP status code [401] with message "Invalid request token." when getting token credentials.`

It used to work just fine. I've tried:

- Deleting my test/dev application in Twitter Dev,
- Regenerating my application keys,
- Making sure the "Enable OAuth" option is checked,
- Enabling the callback lock,

I'm completely stumped, as everything was working, and seems like it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the same bug.
You will work if you modify and override the following methods.

*SocialiteProviders\Manager\OAuth1\Server::getTokenCredentials（）*

```
//$response = $client->post($uri, $headers, $bodyParameters)->send();
$response = $client->post($uri, [
                'headers' => $headers,
                'form_params' => $bodyParameters,
]);
```

Comment: Went to go fix it and found that SocialiteProviders released a fix for it yesterday, thanks: https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/commit/904283bdc4fa149f7455cc29f0bbcafa181149f2